# How can long numbers be allowed to go beyond cell borders in Excel (perhaps with VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

For different reasons I have fixed column widths in an Excel spreadsheet. Now I have to insert numbers, which have multiple digits. And as usual Excel only displays "###" (hashtags) instead of the values, because the numbers are too long for the strongly limited cell widths. But the adjacent cells are empty. So I need some kind of hack that the numbers will overlap into the adjacent cells and get to be displayed correctly.

I have searched the web and did not find a direct solution.

I have tried to transform the values to text and customized formats. With that I had some success, but then I could not use a sum function on these numbers.

-

Comment: The two options I know of are either `=TEXT(123456789,"0")` or select the two columns/cells and center across columns through changing horizontal allignment to be across selection. Allthough the latter might not exactly "overflowing" at least it will let you calculate, while the former is technically transformed into text and would need recalculation through `=VALUE(A1)` or something like `=1*A1` to be used in a `SUM()`

Comment: I have to ask, why not adjust column to "Autofit" if the adjacent cells are Empty and you have room to display entire number?

Comment: Excel by concept will not cheat the user by displaying/printing  only a portion of a number. It will explicitly indicate insufficient space with ##. You have to provide enough space by reducing font size, or merging the necessary amount of cells when you need narrow columns around. But merging will cause difficulties later at sorting or filtering.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, but I have to ask further. If I want to sum up a range of number, which are formatted as text right now and have a format like "12.3%" (with the percentage symbol as part of the string), how could I convert these. I guess, I cannot do something like =SUM(VALUE(A1:A5)). I tried something similar, but it did not work. I am not even sure, if I can use VALUE on a range.

Comment: @JvdV About the horizontal alignment. What adds to the problem is that the numbers are not always in the same column. There position depends on other factors and VBA just fills them in. Still, I will think about that solution.

Comment: As an array you can, will try an answer later to show you

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I understand your question, but for formatting reasons all columns should have the same width in this spreadsheet.

Comment: @AcsErno I know why Excel behaves like this, but still I would like to circumvent it by allowing the numbers to be displayed in full and overlap the adjacent cells. Just like text.

Comment: @JvdV Thanks, I will come back to this post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few examples on how you can still sum ranges that are tecnically text but looking like numbers:

[image]

Notice that the last three formulas are entered as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

I'm sure you can pick up some techniques and apply them, combinations of above are possible too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still I have a problem. I want to generate that formula in VBA and to be inserted two cells below the last list entry. On first view, everything looks great. VBA generates the correct formula (I took your second option with the sumproduct function) in the correct cell. But then it displays again #NAME? I am not sure if this error message is the same in the English Excel version, but I guess it is. However, when I select that cell, go into the formula bar and just hit enter without changing anything, then the correct sum is displayed. I don't get it. :(

Comment: @Mdoe, I'm not quite sure what you are doing wrong but when I use a line, for example: `Cells(1, 3).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5))"` it works just fine

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I am actually not using an English Excel version. So I thought that I had to enter the translation of the sumproduct function name in my VBA code. But instead VBA needed the English function name and then translated it itself as soon as it was used in the spreadsheet. :)